# Sumarle horas a una fecha en un Date Frame

Tags: pandas, date, dataframe, datetime

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo un problema, quiero sumarle a la columna Ingreso desverd,la columna horas iniciales. A su vez esta ultima esta creada a partir de un diccionario relacionado con Color lote. Alguien sabe como hacerlo.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np

df3 = pd.read_excel("C:/Users/nutri/Desktop/ensayos.xlsx",sheet_name=0)
map_dictionary ={'RK6':0,'RK5':24, 'RK4':48,'RK3':72,'RK2':96}
df3['Horas Inicial']= df3['Color lote'].map(map_dictionary)`
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías ocupar la función `pd.to_datetime()` junto con `pd.Timedelta()` para generar una nueva serie que sobreescriba la original.

Primero con `pd.to_datetime()` conviertes la columna desde un dtype `object` a uno `datetime64[ns]`, que es el apropiado para las operaciones con datos temporales.

Como la función `pd.Timedelta()` toma como argumento número y unidad, a cada fila de la serie con la función `apply()`, definiendo como su argumento una función anónima o lambda que aplica `pd.Timedelta()` con los parámetros pasados.

Esto convierte los valores de la serie a `datetime64[ns]`:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Ingreso desverd'])
```

Esto devuelve una serie con cada elemento convertido en un objeto del tipo `Timedelta`, con una duración de `l`, en unidades `h`:

```
df['Horas Inicial'].apply(lambda l: pd.Timedelta(l, unit='h')
```

Y con esto se asigna a la serie existente el valor resultado de la operación:

```
df['Ingreso desverd'] = (
    pd.to_datetime(df['Ingreso desverd']) - 
    df['Horas Inicial'].apply(lambda l: pd.Timedelta(l, unit='h'))
)
```

Espero te sirva! Te dejo el link a documentación de Pandas que te puede orientar sobre el trabajo con Time series y dates.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html